# How can I input a list as column value in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 4 columns ('1', '2', '3' and '4') and about 7 million rows. The values are floats. I would like to add a column with the same value for all rows, where this value is a list. The goal is to do multiplications between a column that contains floats and the column with the lists, so I obtain new lists which are not uniform anymore, because they are multiplied with different values.

Any idea on how to get this column with the list as values, or another solution to reach the goal?
I have had the following errors at the moment:

```
df['list'] = [0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130]
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

df['list'] = [[0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130]]
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1': [0.155, 0.138, ...],
    '2': [0.473, 0.307, ...],
    '3': [0.291, 0.490, ...],
    '4': [0.080, 0.064, ...],

})
```

Idea:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    '1': [0.155, 0.138, ...],
    '2': [0.473, 0.307, ...],
    '3': [0.291, 0.490, ...],
    '4': [0.080, 0.064, ...],
    'list': [[0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130], [0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130], ...]

})
```

Comment: What's stopping you from just adding `df['list']=[[0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130], [0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130]]` with your values? It would help if you add the code that is causing the error.

Comment: because df['list'] needs 7 million rows, instead of two

Comment: Did you try creating the list of lists with list comprehension, then just adding the column to the df?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'1': [1,2], 'list': [[1,2]]*2})` something like this, but replacing the last 2 with either your 7million or `len(df)` might work. So `df['list'] = [[0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130]] * len(df)`.

Comment: This worked indeed, however multiplying the column of floats with the column of constant lists does not :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add the constant list value using this list comprehension:

```
df['list'] = [[0.030, 0.040, 0.750, 0.130] for _ in range(len(df))]
```